# URI and double slashes

Tags: java, uri, rfc3986

```
java.net.URI.create("localhost:8080/foo")   // Works

java.net.URI.create("127.0.0.1:8080/foo")   // Throws exception

java.net.URI.create("//127.0.0.1:8080/foo") // Works
```

Is double slash required for when you have the host as an IP Address? I glanced through the RFC for URI - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986. But could not find anything pertaining to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.net.URI.create` [uses the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) described in [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

```
java.net.URI.create("localhost:8080/foo")
```

This doesn't produce an exception, but the URI is parsed in a way which you probably don't expect. Its *scheme* (not host!) is set to `localhost`, and the `8080/foo` isn't port + path, but a *scheme-specific part*. So this doesn't really work.

```
java.net.URI.create("//localhost:8080/foo")
```

parses the URL without scheme, as a *net_path* grammar element (see RFC 2396 for details).

Here's the relevant grammar excerpt from the RFC 2396:

```
URI-reference = [ absoluteURI | relativeURI ] [ "#" fragment ]

// This is how 'localhost:8080/foo' is parsed:
absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )

relativeURI   = ( net_path | abs_path | rel_path ) [ "?" query ]

... 

// This is how '//127.0.0.1:8080/foo' is parsed: 
net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]

...

// Scheme must start with a letter, 
// hence 'localhost' is parsed as a scheme, but '127' isn't: 
scheme        = alpha *( alpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." )
```

---

One proper way would be:

```
java.net.URI.create("http://localhost:8080/foo")
```